# Assigning static IP to Node application in Google Cloud

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have delpoyed my Node.js application in Google Cloud and need to access our SQL database hosted in GCP. I am not able to configure static IP for the Node app to connect with DB.

Please suggest if configuring static IP in the Node app is the only way or any alternate way to permanently interact with the database hosted in the google cloud. Node app forms the backend of my android app.

Comment: do you use cloud sql or a have your own mysql or otherwise running in one of your instance.

Comment: We are using cloud SQL, i have uploaded my database instance to the SQL engine in GCP

Comment: to clarify you're unable to configure static ip for your DB or you're unable to assign static ip for node, or is it both.

Comment: Static IP for sequel is already configured, not sure how to communicate my node hosted in GCP with my cloud SQL. I tried the method defined in the link  - https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-sql for connecting my node with sql, however, recieved the following error {"status":"Failure","details":"ETIMEDOUT"}, pls suggest

Comment: which step do you get the error at ?

Comment: In Configuring settings section of the same link.

Comment: Not sure where you can go wrong there, do you have a dns configured for your project, I can give you workaround through the console if there is.

Comment: I'm having the same issue trying to connect a Loopback application running on App Engine to Cloud SQL. I get the same `ETIMEDOUT ` error even though they explain that it should magically connect if the App Engine and Cloud SQL are in the same project.